# VS 2017 Diagnostics Tool Profile Entire HTTP Request

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, profiler

I'm trying to Get Profile the CPU usage of my program.   My profile correctly captures the CPU usage on the Visualizer.

[image: Cpu Usage]

However it only display the usage for the Startup.cs thread and no the thread that my operations are set on.   I've set my debug points inside of the code I want to get the cpu usage on.

[image: Code To Profile]

yet the call stack from the Diagnostics tool seems to only pick up from the thread which runs the Middleware pipeline.

[image: Diagnostic call stack]

**EDIT**
Additionally I've check the Filter for Show External Code.  I have all Threads Checked as well,  However it just breaks down the system and does not Show my Code, Even If I Use the filter to search for the DLL that it is executed in

[image]

Just as a guess, the diagnostics tool should be profiling IISExpress instead of Dotnet.exe

Does anyone know how I can profile the entire request, or even just the portion of my code that is run by IIS Express?